# How to find and count each line in a text file using regular expressions in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, text-files

I have a text file that contains:

```
motion
black
lotion
mansion
cardio
sensational
```

How would I use a regular expression to print all the words that contain 'ion'? So it prints:

```
motion 
lotion
mansion 
sensational
```

When it prints I need it to print the word not in a string so it looks like:

```
motion
```

not

```
"motion"
```

The code I have so far is:

```
import re
f = open("file.txt","r")
ex = re.findall("", f)
print ex
```

Comment: The best way would be to start learning about regular expressions and use an online (Python) regex tester to practice making regular expression patterns.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
# file = open('filename').read()
file = '''
motion
black
lotion
mansion
cardio
sensational '''
matchs = re.findall(r'.+ion.*?', string=file)
for word in matchs:
    print(word)
```

out:

```
motion
lotion
mansion
sensation
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a `filter`.

Once you have a list of all the lines, use something like the following:

```
def f(line):
    return re.match(r'ion', line)

matches = filter(f, all_lines)
```

The list `matches` will contain the subset of the lines in `all_lines` which contain 'ion'

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f.read().split('\n'):
        if re.search(r'ion', line):
            print line

Output : 
motion
lotion
mansion
sensational
```